# How can I improve scrolling speed in matplotlib when a figure contains many axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib figure with many axes, and the scrolling/zooming becomes unusably slow. Is there anyway to speed it up?

As an example, try scrolling one of the axes produced with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,plts = plt.subplots(10,10)
plt.show()
```

(I am on a Mac, using the macosx backend. The QT4Agg backend seemed similarly sluggish.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the slowdown comes from matplotlib redrawing the entire figure, rather than just the subplot you want to zoom. I have found that you can speed things up by creating multiple figures and embedding them in a PyQt widget.

Here's a quick proof of concept using `'figure_enter_event'` and a bit of ugly hackery to allow the use of a single navigation toolbar across all figures. Note that I have only attempted to make the pan and zoom features work properly. By peeking at the source of `NavigationToolbar2` in `backend_bases.py` some more I'm sure you could adapt it to your needs.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt5'] = 'PyQt5'
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

import numpy as np

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Construct the plots
        playout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        playout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        for row in range(0, 10):
            for col in range(0, 10):
                fig = Figure()
                ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
                canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
                canvas.mpl_connect('figure_enter_event', self.enterFigure)
                playout.addWidget(canvas, row, col, 1, 1)

                t = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, step=0.01)
                ax.plot(t, np.sin(row*t) + np.cos(col*t))

        # Assign toolbar to first plot
        self.navbar = NavigationToolbar(playout.itemAtPosition(0, 0).widget(), self)

        cwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(cwidget)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.navbar)
        layout.addLayout(playout)
        self.setCentralWidget(cwidget)

    def enterFigure(self, event):
        self.navbar.canvas = event.canvas
        event.canvas.toolbar = self.navbar
        self.navbar._idDrag = event.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.navbar.mouse_move)

        # Toggle control off and then on again for the current canvas
        if self.navbar._active:
            if self.navbar._active == 'PAN':
                self.navbar.pan()
                self.navbar.pan()
            elif self.navbar._active == 'ZOOM':
                self.navbar.zoom()
                self.navbar.zoom()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this right away. Needed to figure out how to install PyQt5 in Anaconda Python (described here: https://anaconda.org/dsdale24/pyqt5). This works great! ...although the solution is more complicated than I would have liked. :)